# Fiber bundle over $SL_2(\mathbb C)/\mathbb C^*$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, fiber-bundles

Let $F:=N/\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is discrete be a compact nilmanifold. I want to construct a fiber bundle over $SL_2(\mathbb C)/\mathbb C^*$ with fiber $N/\Gamma$.

1. I have read somewhere that if one considers the homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb C^* \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(F)$ then $SL_2(\mathbb C)\times_\varphi F $ is an $F$-fiber bundle over $SL_2(\mathbb C)/\mathbb C^*$. Can one explain this construction to me?
2. Can we show that $\varphi (\mathbb C^*)$ is central subgroup of the nilpotent group $N$?
3. Consider $\varphi|_{\mathbb S^1}$. What will the new fiber bundle be?

Comment: 1. Do you know what an associated bundle is? 2. That would be false. 3. No idea what this question even means.

Comment: Can you please explain for me why 2. is false?  for 3. I maybe meant clutching construction!

Comment: @Ronald You must use @[user] to notify the particular user in question. The OP always gets notified when somebody comments.